# Batch update using CGridView

Tags: php, checkbox, yii, cgridview

I want to perform a batch update on some records displayed in a CGridView and using CCheckBoxColumn, but it's not working!
Here is an example scenario:

Consider the table (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Add some rows:

```
INSERT INTO `tb_test` (`id`, `description`, `active`) VALUES  
(1, 'Test #1', 0),  
(2, 'Test #2', 1),  
(3, 'Test #3', 0);
```

Then use Gii to generate defaults Model, Controller and CRUD, ok?

Well, after that, I made some changes in the Controller:

```
// unlock "active" and "ajaxupdate"
public function accessRules()
{
    ...
    array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('active','ajaxupdate'),
        'users'=>array('*'),
    ),
    ...
}

// ...other stuff

// action Active
public function actionActive()
{
    $model=new Test('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Test']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Test'];

    $this->render('active',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

// action AjaxUpdate
public function actionAjaxUpdate()
{
    $check_column = $_POST['check_column'];
    print_r($check_column);
}
```

And, finally, here is the test View:

```
<?php 
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'test-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'enablePagination'=>false,
    'selectableRows'=>2,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'id'=>'check_column',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'value'=>'$data->active',
            'checked'=>'$data->active',
        ),
        'id',
        'description',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
?>

<script>
function reloadGrid(data) {
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('test-grid');
}
</script>

<?php 
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Update All',array('test/ajaxupdate'), array('success'=>'reloadGrid'));

$this->endWidget(); 
?>
```

My objective is to get the values os ALL the check-boxes and perform a batch update on the table, setting the column ACTIVE to true or false.

But the Yii framework just send to Ajax the **marked checks**.
Through the Firebug I can see the result like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
)
```

Even if I mark all 3 records!

Is there a way of getting the values of ALL the check-boxes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st. Selectable rows should look like this:

```
array(
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '2',
            'id'=>'check_column',
            'value'=>'$data->active',
            'checked'=>'$data->active',
      ),
```

2nd. You can pass them by your own, so ajaxButton will look like:

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxButton(Yii::t("app","grid_update"), 'test/ajaxupdate', array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'data'=>'js:{ids : $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("grid-id-here","check_columns").toString()}',
    'success' =>
        'js:function (data) {
               //do what you need here
           }',
), array(
    'id' => 'update_btn_'.rand(0,255),
    'class' => 'update_btn'
));?>
```

With this method you will get string, separated with comma with your selected rows.

Comment: Hi @ineersa! Thanks for your help! 
"With this method you will get string, separated with comma with your selected rows."

That's the problem. I need ALL the rows, not just the selected :/

Comment: well, there's no such method, you can write it by your own, but in my opinion it's kinda useless. As you wrote `perform a batch update on the table, setting the column ACTIVE to true or false`, so just get checked checkboxes and set your ACTIVE to true for them and default value set to false.

Comment: Hi @ineersa! Well, the example I gave was just a fake scenario. The real scenario is more complex, and a method like that would be useful to me. But OK, I'll try a workaround. Thanks!